# How can I determine which font file is being used, not just the font family?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, font-face

Let's say I have the following font face definitions:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("../fonts/open-sans.regular.woff") format("woff");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url('../fonts/open-sans.light.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: url('../fonts/open-sans.semibold.woff') format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('../fonts/open-sans.bold.woff') format('woff');
}
```

In Chrome's dev tools, I can tell which font family is being used:

[image]

But is there a way to tell which specific font file is being used? I'm trying to verify that the browser is actually using the bold version of the font, for example, instead of doing its own 'fake' bolding on the regular version of the font.

Comment: try Firefox it shows the font option in Dev tools

Comment: There is a chrome extension WhatFont available. This is what I use. But it is completely up to you.

Comment: Actually I said crap, in my case the font-name + variant seems to be included in the file itself.

Comment: @nabanita I've tried WhatFont already, it doesn't give me any info aside from what DevTools already provides. I need the specific font file being used, not just the font family.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To answer my own question, Nikul Khatik gave the correct answer. Chrome dev tools doesn't support this feature, but Firefox's does:

[image]
So use Firefox to get the actual font face that's used for an element.

Comment: The [Styles tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference#view) or the [Computed tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css/reference#computed) of Chrome DevTools doesn't give you this information?

Comment: @KayceBasques As I mentioned in my question, I need to determine whether the browser is actually using the Open Sans bold font, or if it's using the Open Sans regular font and applying its own bolding. Chrome dev tools doesn't give you this info because if you have 3 `font-face` definitions that only differ in `font-weight` and the src file used, the font will always be "Open Sans" in Chrome dev tools and you can't tell which specific font file is being used.

Comment: OK, I think I understand the limitation. Thanks for clarifying. I'll open a feature request.

Answer (score 6):

In Chrome there is no way to know which font file is loaded but you can get good hints by check out the "Rendered Fonts" in "Computed" tab and then check font files name in "Application" tab

check Rendered Fonts:

[image: check Rendered Fonts]

check font files name:
[image: check font files name]

Answer (score 2):

- Open Chrome DevTools (Right click > Inspect)
- Go to Sources tab
- Look for the font folder (if you're using Google Font, go to ☁fonts.gstatic.com)
- Open subdirectories if any, you'll get the actual font file being
  used

[image: Chrome DevTools]

Comment: This only shows which fonts are loaded though, not which font is actually used for a particular element. I'm using a mixture of different font weights and styling and I need something definitive that tells me the exact font file used for a given element.

Answer (score -1):

In Safari, in Resources it will tell. you the specific font files that are loaded.

```
Fonts
    fontfileBold.ttf
```